# Decreasing sequence of closed sets in a separable metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, separable-spaces

Is it possible to have an uncountable strictly decreasing sequence $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha<\omega_1}$ $$A_\beta\supsetneq A_\alpha \text{ for all  } \beta<\alpha$$ of closed sets $A_\alpha$ in a separable metric space $X$?

The answer is probable NO, but I need to see a proof cause I don't trust myself today!

Answer (score 1):

Everyone please let me know if this sounds correct:

Suppose $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha<\omega_1}$ is a sequence of closed subsets of $X$ with $A_\beta\supseteq A_\alpha \text{ for all  } \beta<\alpha$.

Then $\{X\setminus A_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_1\}$ is an open cover of $X\setminus \bigcap _{\alpha<\omega_1}A_\alpha$.

Since $X$ is hereditarily Lindelöf, the open cover has a countable subcover $\{X\setminus A_\alpha:\alpha<\gamma\}$ (covering $X\setminus \bigcap _{\alpha<\omega_1}A_\alpha$). In fact, $X\setminus \bigcap _{\alpha<\omega_1}A_\alpha\subseteq X\setminus A_\gamma$.

This means $A_\alpha=A_\beta$ for all $\gamma\leq \alpha\leq\beta$.  So the sequence is *not strictly* decreasing.

Comment: In fact, it is classical that such a strictly decreasing sequence  exists in $X$ iff $X$ is *not* hereditarily Lindelöf. The strictly decreasing open variant exists iff $X$ is *not* hereditarily separable. But for metric spaces separable  = hereditarily separable = hereditarily Lindelöf etc.

Comment: $\beta$ is not defined  in the last line.I think the last line should say $A_a=A_{\gamma}$ for all $a$ such that $\gamma\leq a<\omega_1.$.... Or you could just say that  we must have $A_{\gamma +1}\supset A_{\gamma}.$... But  you are right.